# Working with XML body from Soap call with Nokogiri in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, nokogiri

I'm writing a Ruby script to make a Postman SOAP POST call, then using Nokogiri to to parse the XML response.  When I take the full SOAP call response from Postman, copy it into my editor and manually take the XML body and decode it and format it online I'm able to use the following Nokogiri script successfully:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("response.xml"))

property_ids = []

doc.css('Property').each do |property|
  puts "Property ID: #{property['PropertyId']}"
  property_ids << property['PropertyId']
end


property_ids.each_with_index do |property_id, index|
  puts "index:  #{index}"
  puts "property id: #{property_id}"
end
```

Where I run into the problem is when I want to include in the script the Ruby snippet of the Postman call:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'


url = URI("https://esite.thelyndco.com/AmsiWeb/eDexWeb/esite/leasing.asmx")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request["content-type"] = 'application/soap+xml'
request["cache-control"] = 'no-cache'
request["postman-token"] = '916e3f3d-11ca-e8cf-2066-542b009a281d'
request.body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\r\n  <soap12:Body>\r\n    <GetPropertyList xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\r\n      <UserID>updater</UserID>\r\n      <Password>[password]</Password>\r\n      <PortfolioName>[portfolio name]</PortfolioName>\r\n      <XMLData> \r\n</XMLData>\r\n    </GetPropertyList>\r\n  </soap12:Body>\r\n</soap12:Envelope>"

response = http.request(request)

doc = Nokogiri::XML(response.body)
# doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("full-response.xml"))
# doc.at('GetPropertyListResponse').text
```

What I want to do is take the full SOAP response with the SOAP envelope and be able to process it in my script without having to cut and paste; manually decoding and formatting using online XML formatters.

Commented out are a couple of lines that I tried from Stack Overflow. Is it possible to decode and format the XML body with Nokogiri or to parse out the SOAP envelope?

edit:

By decoding the XML I mean taking:

```
<GetPropertyListResult>&lt;Properties&gt;&lt;Property PropertyId="11A" PropertyName1="1111 Austin Hwy" PropertyName2="" PropertyAddrLine1="The 1111" PropertyAddrLine2="1111 Austin Highway" PropertyAddrLine3="" PropertyAddrLine4="" PropertyAddrCity="San Antonio" PropertyAddrState="TX" PropertyAddrZipCode="78209" PropertyAddrCountry="" PropertyAddrEmail="" RemitToAddrLine1="The 1111" RemitToAddrLine2="1111 Austin Highway" RemitToAddrLine3="" RemitToAddrLine4="" RemitToAddrCity="San Antonio" RemitToAddrState="TX" RemitToAddrZipCode="78209" RemitToAddrCountry="" LiveDate="2013-12-04T00:00:00" MgrOffPhoneNo="210-804-1100" MgrFaxNo="" MgrSalutation="" MgrFirstName="" MgrMiName="" MgrLastName="" MonthEndInProcess="N"&gt;&lt;Amenity PropertyId="11A"
```

and decoding it into using this [online XML decoder](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml&action=encode&charset=us_ascii):

```
<GetPropertyListResult><Properties><Property PropertyId="11A" PropertyName1="1111 Austin Hwy" PropertyName2="" PropertyAddrLine1="The 1111" PropertyAddrLine2="1111 Austin Highway" PropertyAddrLine3="" PropertyAddrLine4="" PropertyAddrCity="San Antonio" PropertyAddrState="TX" PropertyAddrZipCode="78209" PropertyAddrCountry="" PropertyAddrEmail="" RemitToAddrLine1="The 1111" RemitToAddrLine2="1111 Austin Highway" RemitToAddrLine3="" RemitToAddrLine4="" RemitToAddrCity="San Antonio" RemitToAddrState="TX" RemitToAddrZipCode="78209" RemitToAddrCountry="" LiveDate="2013-12-04T00:00:00" MgrOffPhoneNo="210-804-1100" MgrFaxNo="" MgrSalutation="" MgrFirstName="" MgrMiName="" MgrLastName="" MonthEndInProcess="N"><Amenity PropertyId="11A"
```

then running it through an [XML formatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html) so that nested elements are indented for legibility.

Comment: What do do the verbs 'decode' and 'format' mean in this case?  What are you actually doing by hand that you need done with the Ruby code?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill, edited question for clarification on xml decoding and formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to decode and format the XML:

```
require "nokogiri"

XML_CHAR_ENTITIES = {
  "lt"  => "<",
  "gt"  => ">",
  "amp" => "&",
  "num" => "#",
  "comma" => ","
}

xsl =<<XSL
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
XSL


xml = '<GetPropertyListResult>&lt;Properties&gt;&lt;Property PropertyId="11A" PropertyName1="1111 Austin Hwy" PropertyName2="" PropertyAddrLine1="The 1111" PropertyAddrLine2="1111 Austin Highway" PropertyAddrLine3="" PropertyAddrLine4="" PropertyAddrCity="San Antonio" PropertyAddrState="TX" PropertyAddrZipCode="78209" PropertyAddrCountry="" PropertyAddrEmail="" RemitToAddrLine1="The 1111" RemitToAddrLine2="1111 Austin Highway" RemitToAddrLine3="" RemitToAddrLine4="" RemitToAddrCity="San Antonio" RemitToAddrState="TX" RemitToAddrZipCode="78209" RemitToAddrCountry="" LiveDate="2013-12-04T00:00:00" MgrOffPhoneNo="210-804-1100" MgrFaxNo="" MgrSalutation="" MgrFirstName="" MgrMiName="" MgrLastName="" MonthEndInProcess="N"&gt;&lt;Amenity PropertyId="11A"></GetPropertyListResult>'

xml = xml.gsub(/&(\w+);/) do |match|
  char_entity = XML_CHAR_ENTITIES[$1]
  char_entity ? char_entity : match
end

doc  = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
xslt = Nokogiri::XSLT(xsl)
xml  = xslt.transform(doc)

puts "#{xml}"
```

The XML provided was incomplete, so this terminating string was appended to allow it to be parsed: `></GetPropertyListResult>`

The XML_CHAR_ENTITIES provides a hash of encoded strings to decoded strings, and can be easily extended to include other XML character entities, such as those documented at the [W3 Character Entity Reference Chart](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

XSL is an embedded stylesheet that is used to format the XML for output with Nokogiri.

Decoding the XML character entities is done with the `String#gsub` call using the block option.  The XML is then successfully parsed by Nokogiri.  Once the XML is parsed, it is formatted using Nokogiri XSLT transformation.

The output of this code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetPropertyListResult>
  <Properties>
    <Property PropertyId="11A" PropertyName1="1111 Austin Hwy" PropertyName2="" PropertyAddrLine1="The 1111" PropertyAddrLine2="1111 Austin Highway" PropertyAddrLine3="" PropertyAddrLine4="" PropertyAddrCity="San Antonio" PropertyAddrState="TX" PropertyAddrZipCode="78209" PropertyAddrCountry="" PropertyAddrEmail="" RemitToAddrLine1="The 1111" RemitToAddrLine2="1111 Austin Highway" RemitToAddrLine3="" RemitToAddrLine4="" RemitToAddrCity="San Antonio" RemitToAddrState="TX" RemitToAddrZipCode="78209" RemitToAddrCountry="" LiveDate="2013-12-04T00:00:00" MgrOffPhoneNo="210-804-1100" MgrFaxNo="" MgrSalutation="" MgrFirstName="" MgrMiName="" MgrLastName="" MonthEndInProcess="N">
      <Amenity PropertyId="11A"/>
    </Property>
  </Properties>
</GetPropertyListResult>
```